# Xpages: 'RichText' field on web and saving with java bean

Tags: xpages

I have a requirement to allow users to enter 'RichText' in a field in an Xpages form on the web. It is just rich text (bold, size, color) no attachments/links/pictures. And no need to edit it on the client.

I have googled this and put together something that kind of is close, but doesn't work. I am only trying to get a minimal working example right now.

Used [some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286748/using-rich-text-with-java-managed-bean-in-xpages) in this link and in another one I cannot find right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Xpage:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
    <xp:panel id="pnlAll">
        <xp:this.data>  
            <xe:objectData saveObject="#{javascript:docModel.save()}"
                var="docModel">
                <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:var docModel = new com.scoular.model.Doc();
var unid = sessionScope.get("key");
if (unid != null) {
    docModel.loadByUnid(unid);
    sessionScope.put("key","");
    viewScope.put("readOnly","Yes");
} else {
    docModel.create();
    viewScope.put("readOnly","No");
}
return docModel;}]]></xe:this.createObject>
            </xe:objectData>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
            value="#{docModel.body}">
        </xp:inputRichText>
        <xp:button value="Save" 
        id="button1" 
        type="button" 
        styleClass="btn-primary">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" save="true">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (docModel.save() == true) {
}}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>

    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Java:

```java
package com.scoular.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openntf.domino.Database;

import lotus.domino.MIMEEntity;
import lotus.domino.Stream;
import org.openntf.domino.DateTime;
import org.openntf.domino.Document;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;
import org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogUtil;

public class Doc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5867831497684227875L;
    private com.ibm.xsp.http.MimeMultipart body;

    // Common Fields
    private String unid;
    private Boolean newNote;
    private DateTime crtDte;
    private String crtUsr;

    public Doc() {

    }

    public void create() {
        try {   
            newNote = true;
            Session session = Factory.getSession();
            Date date = new Date();
            crtDte = session.createDateTime(date);
            crtUsr = session.getEffectiveUserName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }

    public void loadByUnid(String unid) {
        try {
            Session session = Factory.getSession();
            String DataDBpath = session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer() + "!!" + "scoApps\\Spectrum\\cashmarkData.nsf";
            Database DataDB = session.getDatabase(DataDBpath);
            Document doc = DataDB.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
            if (null == doc) {
                System.out.println("Document not found");
            } else {
                loadValues(doc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }

    public void loadValues(Document doc) {
        try {
            // common fields
            newNote = false;
            unid = doc.getUniversalID();
            crtDte = doc.getItemValue("checkInDate", DateTime.class);
            crtUsr = doc.getItemValueString("crtUsr");

            // custom fields


        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }
    public boolean save() {

        boolean tmpSave = true;

        try {

            Document doc = null;
            Session session = Factory.getSession();
            String DataDBpath = session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer() + "!!" + "scoApps\\Spectrum\\cashmarkData.nsf";
            Database DataDB = session.getDatabase(DataDBpath);

            if (newNote) {
                doc = DataDB.createDocument();
                doc.put("form", "doc");
            } else {
                doc = DataDB.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
            }

            //Create the body as a MIME entity
            session.setConvertMIME(false); // Do not convert MIME to RT         MIMEEntity body = doc.createMIMEEntity("body");
            Stream stream = session.createStream();
            stream.writeText("<ul><li>hello</li><li>world</li></ul><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>");
            //body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT);
            stream.close();

            doc.save();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
        return tmpSave;
    }

    // Getters and Setters for common fields

    public String getUnid() {
        return unid;
    }

    public void setUnid(String unid) {
        this.unid = unid;
    }

    public Boolean getNewNote() {
        return newNote;
    }

    public void setNewNote(Boolean newNote) {
        this.newNote = newNote;
    }

    public DateTime getCrtDte() {
        return crtDte;
    }

    public void setCrtDte(DateTime crtDte) {
        this.crtDte = crtDte;
    }

    public String getCrtUsr() {
        return crtUsr;
    }

    public void setCrtUsr(String crtUsr) {
        this.crtUsr = crtUsr;
    }


       public com.ibm.xsp.http.MimeMultipart getBody() {
           return body;
       }

       public void setbody(com.ibm.xsp.http.MimeMultipart body) {
           this.body = body;
       }

}
```

Comment: I generally avoid RichText fields like the plague these days. I've been trying to remember where I last saw an example of this, but it may have been from the SO thread you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

To save your MimeMultipart to a MimeEntity field give this a try:

```
String fieldName = "yourFieldName";

if (doc.hasItem(fieldName))
    doc.removeItem(fieldName);

Stream stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText(body.getHTML());

MIMEEntity mimeEnt = doc.createMIMEEntity(fieldName);
mimeEnt.setContentFromText(stream,
    "text/html;charset=UTF-8", MIMEntity.ENC_NONE);
stream.close();
stream.recycle();
```

Also you may want to remove some CKEditor plugins by adding a dojoAttribute called 'removePlugins'

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="removePlugins" 
            value="ibmxspimage,smiley,ibmsametimeemoticons"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

This will remove the toolbar buttons that allow the user to choose emoticons / upload images (which will cause an error)

Note however this will not prevent users from trying to paste Images into the CKEditor, to prevent that you need to make/obtain a custom CKEditor plugin that prevents pasting images both via a 'Data URL' (clipboard paste) or via 'Href' e.g. web address based images.