# data binding Rich text field to xp:inputRichText control with Java

Tags: java, xpages, richtext

I want to open a document in an XPage. The data binding occurs via a managed bean. It happens to be that 1 field on the document is of type Rich Text although all contents are just plain text (a simple comment field, but set as Rich Text on a Domino form).

Since this is a legacy application with thousands of documents I would rather not change the field type and update the documents are what so ever.

On the web I found a hint that I should search in the MimeMultipart.fromHTML direction but I have not found a sample that:
- reads the data in the rich text field on a document
- puts it in a property of my java class/managed bean
- bind it to a rich text control (or something similar) on my XPage.

Can anyone provide some samples incuding some guidance??

Comment: Since you just want to store plain text, does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12803688/785061

Comment: not sure if I understand it correctly? when I want to load information from a rich text field document, how do I specify this? employee.setComment(doc.???);